# attach key name to value in a json array result

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a code snippet in spring controller and DAO classes that fetches data from the database. The end result is to get a json output. When the result is processed, it displays just the array without displaying the name of the value-pair. Below is a snippet

dao class snippet

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Object[]> getResult(String no) {
        List <Object[]> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Object[]> results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select i.F_NO, i.LAST_NAME, i.FIRST_NAME, i.HOME_PHONE, i.SEX_NO from Data i where f_no = :f_no")
                .setParameter("_no",  no).list();
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(results)){
            Object firstDataOccurence = results.get(0);
            dataList.add((Object[]) firstDataOccurence);
            return dataList;
        }
        else{
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

controller snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData/{tin}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Object[]> getData(@PathVariable("no") String searchName) {

        searchName = searchName.trim();

        List <Object[]> dataList= myDao.getResult(searchName);


        return dataList;

    }
```

now with the above my output becomes

```
[["100123","demo12","demo7","demo9","demo19","demo28","demo27","demo4","demo5","demo24","demo20"]]
```

with above result, u find out that the keyname is not there. Please how can I get a key:value pairs in my json response.

Comment: sorry where is my wrong to get a downvote on this. This is just a fair attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Step 1) Instead of Object list you can create a POJO and set the value
>   of db Object list to a pojo.
>
> Step 2) You need to convert your normal list to JsonArray .Please
>   follow following steps to do so.

```
List <Object[]> results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select i.F_NO, i.LAST_NAME, i.FIRST_NAME, i.HOME_PHONE, i.SEX_NO from Data i where f_no = :f_no")
                .setParameter("_no",  no).list();
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
try
{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    for (NewPojo obj: results)
    {
         JSONObject studentJSON = new JSONObject();
         studentJSON.put("objfname", obj.getFName());
         studentJSON.put("objlname ", obj.getLName());
         jArray.put(studentJSON);
    }
    jObject.put("NewList", jArray);
} catch (JSONException jse) {
    jse.printStacktrace();
}
```

Note : You can also use JSONObject also if you need

```
Ref links:
```

http://www.java2novice.com/java-json/javax.json/create-json-array/

[How to Create JSONArray for a List<Class name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796881/how-to-create-jsonarray-for-a-listclass-name)

Comment: u did not add the return statement. I am currently implementing your answer and I am stuck merging it into what I already have

Comment: this is not the entire code .I just gave the sample snippet .You need to modify on top of it .

Comment: Don't you know how to create POJO? and your DAO should now return JsobObject instead of list.Please try by yourself if you want all the code then you will not learn anything .