# Spring Boot API Post Mapping to read in Array

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, backend

I currently have an API that has this payload (from a react-select using isMulti):

```
 {
    "college_school_code": [
        {
            "label": "College Name - College Address",
            "value": "1234"
        },
        {
            "label": "College Name - College Address",
            "value": "5678"
        }
    ],
    "userid": "email@email.com"
}
```

I need to read that API in, and write the userid and value of each college_school_codes to a database (so this call would write out two rows, both with the same userid, but different college_school_codes).

Here's some more code that clearly doesn't work.  It should looks to see if there's any current rows for the user, remove those, then add the new rows:

{ @Entity
public class CollegeSchoolCode {

```
@Id
private String label;
private String value;

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}
}

```
@Entity
```

public class CollegeSchoolCode {

```
@Id
private String label;
private String value;

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

```
 public void insertColleges(@RequestBody CollegesInfo newCollegesInfo, CollegeSchoolCode newCollegeSchoolCode){

    String userid = newCollegesInfo.getUserid();
    List college_school_code  = newCollegesInfo.getCollege_school_code();

    System.out.println("colleges="+college_school_code);

    int rowCount = insertCollegesRepository.getRowCount(userid);

    if (rowCount > 0){
        insertCollegesRepository.deleteColleges(userid);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < college_school_code.size(); i++) {
        String value = newCollegeSchoolCode.getValue();
        insertCollegesRepository.insertColleges(userid, value);
    }
}
```

At this point, the app is stepping through my college_school_code list and inserting into the database as expected, but the value for the school code is always null, so there's a disconnect there somewhere that I cannot figure out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create JSONArray for a List<Class name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796881/how-to-create-jsonarray-for-a-listclass-name)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so?  I think the part that's really throwing me off is that I already have a Json, but I need to pull out the list that is a level deep within the Json.

Comment: I really think I need to update the line = String value = newCollegeSchoolCode.getValue(); 

That line doesn't know that I should be looking at college_school_code(i), but I really can't figure out how to accomplish that.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out, and it was a simple one!  I updated the value string to:

```
String value = college_school_code.get(i).getValue();
```

I didn't actually need to add the newCollegeSchoolCode piece like I though, it's always the simple solutions.